# Notices these bumps on my dog. Not sure what it is?

Tags: diseases

[image] Noticed these bumps on my dog. Not sure how long they have been there...

Comment: It's hard to tell from your picture but do you mean the nipples of your dog? Males and females have them and usually there are 8 - 10 of them in 2 rows.

Comment: you need to give more details,what part of your dog is the picture of,and gender-type-age.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to tell from the picture, but I agree that they look rather like nipples.

If they aren't nipples, they might be the cysts. Older dogs often get benign (non-cancerous) cysts that are basically deposits of fat. Definitely have your vet take a look at them to make sure that they aren't cancer, although the likelihood is low.